# ¿cómo programo la acción de esta toolbar? PreferenceActivity en android studio

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

buen día, tengo una `PreferenceActivity` que se ve de la siguiente manera:
[image: Preference activity]

El problema que tengo, es que quiero asignarle una acción al botón de arriba a la izquierda de la pantalla (la flecha de atrás, al lado izquierdo de *Configuración*), el `NavigationDrawer`, sé que es con el `setNavigationOnClickListener` pero no sé dónde ni en qué parte del código debo ponerlo,lo más cercano que encontré fue este bloque de código:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }
```

Pero la propiedad `setNavigationOnClickListener` no me aparece entre las disponibles. Recalco que la pantalla de preferencias la generé desde la plantilla de android Studio.

Cuando se utiliza el botón mencionado desde los fragmentos, regresa a esta pantalla, pero el botón de esta pantalla en específico no me permite asignarle acción.

Answer (score 0):

Yo he añadido una imagen llamada back2 que es una flecha como la que muestras y con el siguiente código me devuelve a la activity anterior.

```
Toolbar toolbarTop = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbarTop.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.back2);

    toolbarTop.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta compañero, pero el problema es que el método `setNavigationOnClickListener` no me lo reconoce el toolbar desde una `PreferenceActivity`